# Is there an equivalent for func.random() in SQLAlchemy for querying a teradata database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I want to query a random row selection from a teradata database with SQLAlchemy. Basically I want to translate the following statement (which works for SQLite) so it also works for teradata.

```
sample = session.query(sample_table_name).order_by(func.random()).limit(1000)
```

Is there an equivalent for `func.random()` which works with teradata? I know that for example for an Oracle DB you need to replace it by `text('dbms_random.value')`.

Comment: The [SAMPLE clause](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/2_MC9vCtAJRlKle2Rpb0mA/XTSw8n_~xbTDRIHwHyUiWA) looks promising, but I don't know if the Teradata SQLAlchemy dialect provides support for it. If not, producing your own compilation extension for it is not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the `sqlalchemy` bit, but you can use `SAMPLE` to get a sampling of rows:

```sql
-- Pseudo-randomized (faster)
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
SAMPLE 1000
;

-- Simple random sample (takes longer)
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
SAMPLE RANDOMIZED ALLOCATION 1000
;
```

Comment: just to add SAMPLE delivers a statistical sample of n rows (SAMPLE 100) or n% (SAMPLE 0.2). If you want to save the statistical computation and have just a few records, take TOP (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM myTable;)